# ReactDOMServer.renderToString() - What exactly does it do?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I know it just renders HTML as text, so speaking of class components, only `contructor()` and `render()` methods are invoked during the `renderToString()`. But I've noticed some weird behavior with regards to function components. Consider the following component example:

```
function MyComponent() {

  console.log(1);

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      Some text
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

I just use `console.log()` inside of function component, which, I guess, is equivalent to `constructor()` method inside of a class component.

`renderToString()` is invoked inside express route handler:

```
import { ServerStyleSheets, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import theme from 'mui/theme';
import App from 'components/App';

const SERVER_PORT = 8081; // Port for Express to listen

const app = express();

app.get('*', async (req, res) => {
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();

  const inlineApp = renderToString(
    sheets.collect(
      <Provider store={exampleStore}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <App />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Provider>,
    ),
  );

  const css = sheets.toString();

  const renderedHTML = `
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style id="jss">${css}</style>
        <title>Repl.it</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${inlineApp}</div>
        <script>
        window.STATE = ${JSON.stringify(exampleStore.getState())};
        </script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
    `;

  res.send(renderedHTML);
});

app.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${SERVER_PORT}`);
});
```

The problem is I'm getting the console output twice when invoking `ReactDOMServer.renderToString()` once. I dont use double rendering on server side.
So I have two questions:

- Can you explain what's exactly happening here?
- If it is a correct behavior, then is there a way to run some code only once during the `renderToString()`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `MyComponent ` multiple times on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough data to make a definitive diagnosis, but may it be that you run in React's strict mode?

Take a look at this: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally **double-invoking** the following functions:
>
> - Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
> - Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
> - **Function component bodies**
> - State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
> - Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

If that's not the case... and I don't actually see `<StrictMode>` in your code, then it'd be nice if you'd make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

Also note, that while function component bodies invoked twice in strict mode, `console.log()`s, starting from *React 17*, are overwritten so that you should see only one record on the console. But that can change. [Not everybody happy with that](https://dev.to/sebastianstamm/be-careful-with-console-log-when-using-react-strictmode-ah9#personal-opinion) and now there is a [PR](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/19710) to at least opt-out from this behavior.

Comment: Strict mode [disables double logging](https://dev.to/sebastianstamm/be-careful-with-console-log-when-using-react-strictmode-ah9)!

Comment: @Mordechai, not really. Only `Starting with React 17` see on [the same page](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects). But that's a good point, that should be mentioned. Will update my answer

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here might be the play of React's Strict mode.

React app when running in strict mode, intentionally double invokes certain functions (e.g. the component's constructor in this case), in order to make it easier to spot and identify easy to miss side-effects during the development phase, which may create issue in production.

You can read about react strict mode in detail here - [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

However it's important to know that Strict Mode double invokes functions only in development environment and not in Production.

Comment: Strict mode [disables double logging](https://dev.to/sebastianstamm/be-careful-with-console-log-when-using-react-strictmode-ah9)!

Comment: Only from React 17.0 and above version. Atleast that's what mentioned in the docs.